# Transformation corresponding to a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Can anybody refer me to some kind of animation tool available online ,which helps to show the transformation corresponding to a matrix.
Also I want to know how symmetric matrix transform the space .
I hope my question is clear.

Comment: You might find [this video](https://youtu.be/kYB8IZa5AuE?t=203) to be useful.  It doesn't say anything in particular about symmetric matrices, though.

Comment: Someone also made their own interactive version of the gridline effect [here](https://shadanan.github.io/MatVis/).

Comment: Wowwwwww thanks for that bro

Answer (score 0):

There is a very instructive course that uses animation to explain linear algebra in this Youtube Channel called [*3Blue1Brown*](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab). It is really great and very useful in my opinion. It is a part of the Khan Academy and alredy ware pointed in comments.